# Dart-lang, how can I map List<int> to List<String> with combining elements?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list

final List list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

how can I "map" to the output as a new List like:

```
"1 and 2",
"3 and 4",
"5 and 6",
"7"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that using the following function:

```
_getComponents(list) => list.isEmpty ? list :
  ([list
    .take(2)
    .join(' and ')
   ]..addAll(_getComponents(list.skip(2))));
```

Call that function like:

```
List outPut = _getComponents(yourList);
```

Explanation:

- You are declaring a recursive function called `_getComponents`
- As the first statement you are checking whether the parameter list is empty, if it's empty returning the parameter as is
- If the list is not empty

  - You are taking the first 2 items from the list using [take](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Iterable/take.html) function
  - You are joining those elements using [join](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Iterable/join.html) function
  - You are calling the [addAll](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/List/addAll.html) function and supplies the result of recursive _getComponents call as it's argument
  - And as the parameter of that _getComponents function you are passing the list, after skipping the first 2 elements using the [skip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/skip.html) function

Answer (score 0):

Answer came off the top of my head but try this:

```
final List list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  List<String> grouped = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      if (i + 1 < list.length) {
        grouped.add("${list[i]} and ${list[i + 1]}");
      } else {
        grouped.add("${list[i]}");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  print(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
main(){
  final List list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  final List newList = [];
  for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
    var string;
    if(i+1<list.length){
      string = "${list[i]} and ${list[i+1]}";
      i++;
    }else{
      string = "${list[i]}";
    }
    newList.add(string);
  }
  print(newList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
void main(){
 final List oldList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
 final List newList = [];
    for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i += 2){

       if(i+1<oldList.length){
          newList.add("${oldList[i]} and ${oldList[i+1]}");
       }else{
          newList.add("${oldList[i]}");
       }
    }
    print(newList);
 }
```